# Error inputing file picture on retrofit2 showing IllegalStateException on gson

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to upload a file (picture) to the server using Retrofit 2. I'm following the tutorial that given, but i still got some error.

Here is the error response:
D/Failed: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Here is my code :
Call call = RetrofitClient
                .getInstance().getApi().loginAndroid(username, password);

```
    //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
            LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();
            int Responsecode = response.code();
           if(Responsecode != 200)
           {
               try {
                   JSONObject jObjError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
                   Log.d("login", String.valueOf(jObjError));
                   Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, jObjError.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Email / Password Salah", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           } else {
               Log.d("response", response.body().toString());
               SharedPrefManager.getInstance(LoginActivity.this)
                       .saveUser(loginResponse.getData());
               Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdminHomeActivity.class);
               intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
               startActivity(intent);
                //Log.d("shared",SharedPrefManager.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).getUser().getNama().toString());
            }
```

This is my model:
private int id;
    private String username, nama, role, branch;

```
public User(int id, String username, String nama, String role, String branch)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.nama = nama;
    this.role = role;
    this.branch = branch;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getNama() {
    return nama;
}

public String getRole() {
    return role;
}

public String getBranch() {
    return branch;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setNama(String nama) {
    this.nama = nama;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public void setBranch(String branch) {
    this.branch = branch;
}
```

And here is my API call:

```
@Multipart
@POST("sparepart")
Call<SparepartResponse> addSparepart(
        @Part("id") String id,
        @Part("nama") String nama,
        @Part("merk") String merk,
        @Part("harga_beli") Integer hargaBeli,
        @Part("harga_jual") Integer hargaJual,
        @Part("stok") Integer stok,
        @Part("stok_minimal") Integer stokMinimal,
        @Part("penempatan") String penempatan,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part gambar,
        @Part("id_sparepart_type") Integer idSparepartType
        );
```

I'm new to retrofit anyway, any help? Thank you

Comment: Post the API's response (json) please.

Comment: Most likely, your required output from the API (LoginResponse and its fields) does not match exactly with what the API is returning. The API is most likely returning just an String not the LoginResponse object.

Comment: @AdibFaramarzi my api response is {
    "data": {
        "id": "SVG-AXX-043",
        "nama": "BUSI LALALA",
        "merk": "ALALA",
        "harga_beli": "20000",
        "harga_jual": "25000",
        "stok": "30",
        "stok_minimal": "10",
        "penempatan": "DPN-RAK-005",
        "gambar": "adbc3e305ac7eb1c25f7963bf7390528cb32dbc6.png",
        "tipe_sparepart": "Kelistrikan"
    }
}

Comment: Add your class definition for SparepartResponse too